# working with particles to make grass in the wind

Tags: animation, particles

I built a grass object, added ParticleInstance modifier, set the target to the plain field object, populated the grass with particles (in the plain field object), added Wind and Turbulence force field objects.

Now, the grass does not move. Any way to fix this?
[image]

Comment: did you check "hair dynamics"? if yes, pls provide blend file

Comment: how do you share the blend file? There is no attachment.

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instrucions

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ukgRj-SNVtkR8b2P4WUV1aRk3tIDdbS/view?usp=sharing